# C# VS: How to make the changes constant every time the form is loaded

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, constants

I'm making a simple program using Visual Studio C#

The program is about Garage reservation system. 
in the reservation form the user will choose a level from the drop down list and 10 labels will appear according to his request. User will click on the spot he needs (the label now will have a car image on it-means spot is reserved- ) then get the ticket.

My issue is when the user returns to home page and get back to the reservation form, and again choose the same level he chose before.. the labels will appear clean and empty as no one have reserved before.

My Question, what is the best way to make the label image and text changes and never return to its default every time the form is loaded?

I have declared two arrays of labels, and I have actually added 20 invisible labels.

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{

      Label[] level1 = new Label[10];
     Label[] level2 = new Label[10];
```

and I assigned the labels in the constructor:

```
public Form3()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        label4.Click += new EventHandler(SpotChosen);
        label5.Click += new EventHandler(SpotChosen);
        label6.Click += new EventHandler(SpotChosen);
        label7.Click += new EventHandler(SpotChosen);
        label8.Click += new EventHandler(SpotChosen);
        label9.Click += new EventHandler(SpotChosen);
        label10.Click += new EventHandler(SpotChosen);
        label11.Click += new EventHandler(SpotChosen);
        label12.Click += new EventHandler(SpotChosen);
        label13.Click += new EventHandler(SpotChosen);

        label14.Click += new EventHandler(SpotChosen);
        label15.Click += new EventHandler(SpotChosen);
        label16.Click += new EventHandler(SpotChosen);
        label17.Click += new EventHandler(SpotChosen);
        label18.Click += new EventHandler(SpotChosen);
        label19.Click += new EventHandler(SpotChosen);
        label20.Click += new EventHandler(SpotChosen);
        label21.Click += new EventHandler(SpotChosen);
        label22.Click += new EventHandler(SpotChosen);
        label23.Click += new EventHandler(SpotChosen);

        level1[0] = label4;
        level1[1] = label5;
        level1[2] = label6;
        level1[3] = label7;
        level1[4] = label8;
        level1[5] = label9;
        level1[6] = label10;
        level1[7] = label11;
        level1[8] = label12;
        level1[9] = label13;

        level2[0] = label14;
        level2[1] = label15;
        level2[2] = label16;
        level2[3] = label17;
        level2[4] = label18;
        level2[5] = label19;
        level2[6] = label20;
        level2[7] = label21;
        level2[8] = label22;
        level2[9] = label23;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all - Naming. So many labels with name labelN. It's easy to get mixed up. Also you do not need 23 times to set event handler, you can iterate through specific labels and assign one event handler for all of them. I suggest you to solve this mishmash with labels. Maybe you need to write UserControl also.

Second. Try to use patterns Singleton or State, or better to implement your windows forms application in MVC/MVP style. At least Singleton will be easiest solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Every time your form loads, labels are re-rendered and they take default values you set to them.

There are many techniques that you can preserve the last state of the controls you have.
Basically you need to store a flag of the labels state in memory when the reservation form is closed.
This can be done on the Form_unload event and one technique you could use is save them in a  static Dictionary where the string key could be the label id, and the SomeFlagType is some type you are using to mark that this "Spot is reserved", if i didn't get you wrong. So your value could be a boolean flag, or even a value that you stored in your control that you want to preserve.

On the Form_Load event you can "query" the dictionary by your label's id and return the flag or value and apply it on the label.

In case it is a multi-user client-server environment, and you want to store your static dictionary on the server side for everyone to query, it would be a slightly different approach.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use a panel in your form (where you can put all your labels) so that you can add the event handlers to all the labels in this way :

```
 foreach (Control c in Panel1.Controls)
       {
                c.Click += SpotChosen;
       }
 private void SpotChosen(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          var label = sender as Label;

      }
```

And for saving the settings of your controls, I think you can use `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755.aspx